# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to com.model.Employee - Spring Batch Async

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm working on `Spring Batch v2.1.3.RELEASE` and using the AsyncItemProcessor to process all the records and its hitting the other tables to get the data out of it.

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to com.model.Employee
    at com.writer.EmployeeWriter.write(EmployeeWriter.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:188) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:154) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:212) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.controller.ReferenceDataLoader.getLoadRefData(ReferenceDataLoader.java:74) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

EmployeeBatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class EmployeeBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> EmployeeReader() throws Exception {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setSql(SQL);

        reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> EmployeeProcessor() {
        return new EmployeeProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception{
        AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(EmployeeProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        asyncItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeWriter EmployeeWriter() {
        return new EmployeeWriter();
    }
}
```

EmployeeJob.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EmployeeJob {
    @Value( "${spring.chunk.size}")
    private String chunkSize;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> EmployeeReader;

    @Autowired
    public AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> asyncItemProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeWriter EmployeeWriter;

    @Bean
    public EmployeeStepExecuListner EmployeeStepExecuListner() {
        return new EmployeeStepExecuListner();
    }

    @Bean("readEmployeeJob")
    @Primary
    public Job readEmployeeJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readEmployeeJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(EmployeeStepOne())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step EmployeeStepOne() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("EmployeeStepOne")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunkSize))
                .reader(EmployeeReader)
                .processor((ItemProcessor)asyncItemProcessor)
                .writer(EmployeeWriter)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error occurs here ```at com.writer.CountryWriter.write(CountryWriter.java:48) ~[classes/:na]```. The source code of ```CountryWriter.java``` could be useful to analyze the error

Comment: Sorry for Typo, its EmployeeWriter class, Added that class as well, could you please suggest now ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the type of managed bean, of your writer, like `public class EmployeeWriter<Employee> implements ItemWriter<Employee>` (same thing with `Autowired`)? Else, which one is row 48?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very used to Spring Batch but, as you use an `AsyncItemProcessor`, I think you should assign an `AsyncItemWriter` as a writer. This `AsyncItemWriter` will then delegate the writing to your existing `EmployeeWriter` :

```java
    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemWriter() throws Exception{
        AsyncItemWriter<Employee> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        // Delegate to EmployeeWriter
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(EmployeeWriter());
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;  
    }

    @Bean
    public Step EmployeeStepOne() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("EmployeeStepOne")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunkSize))
                .reader(EmployeeReader)
                .processor((ItemProcessor)asyncItemProcessor)
                // Change the writer here
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
```